# How to detect changes observable in child-component in Angular 14

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular14

In the parent component, I've defined an Observable variable named results$, and in the view, it is utilized as follows:

controller:

```
this.result$ = this.firstObservable$.pipe(
      combineLatestWith(
        this.secondObservable$.pipe(filter((task) => !!task.key)),
      ),
      switchMap(([first, second]: [type1, type2]) => {

        // some logic here happend

      map((businessFunctionResult: businessFunctionType[]) => ({
        data: businessFunctionResult,
        isLoading: false,
      })),
      catchError((error: unknown) => {
        const err = error as HttpErrorResponse;
        return of({ error: err, isLoading: false });
      })
     
    );
```

view:

```
<div *ngIf="result$ | async as result">
  <container *ngIf="!result.isLoading && result.data">
    <child-component1 [data]="result.data"></child-component1>
    <child-component2 [data]="result.data"></child-component2>
    ...
  </container>
</div>
```

In the child-component, an Input is present, and each child component implements the `OnInit` lifecycle hook. However, when the value of results changes or updates, the child components do not reflect these changes.

```
export class ChildComponent1
  implements OnInit
{
  
  @Input() data!: any[];
ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.data);
}
}
```

An alternative solution involves replacing `ngIf` with `ngFor` in the code. By adopting this approach, the child components are successfully updated. While this solution may seem less straightforward, but its not such a clear solution because the component will be initialized every time.

```
<div *ngFor="let result of [result$ | async]">
  <container *ngIf="!result.isLoading && result.data">
    <child-component1 [data]="result.data"></child-component1>
    <child-component2 [data]="result.data"></child-component2>
  </container>
</div>
```

I know I can use `ngOnChanges` in child components, but for some issues (refactoring, etc.) I don't want to do it.

I want to update the child components every time `result$` has a new value.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/child-component-apmu9m?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: actually not. but I just used @input() as setter.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use `ngChanges`, you could make your `@Input()` a setter and do your logic there:

```js
export class ChildComponent {
  public myData: string;

  @Input() set data(value: string) {
    console.log('@Input()', value);
    this.myData = value;
  }
}
```

Here the setter logic will be executed whenever the input value changes.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-77899228?file=app%2Fchild.component.ts&devtoolsHeight=60)

Answer (score 0):

What about to work with behaviroSubject instead of input ?

Like I would create service with behaviorSubject.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('default message');
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }

}
```

And in parent component you could set new value or even in child. It works both way.

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  message:string;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }
  
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

And listen in one of that component.

```
export class ChildOrSiblingComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  message:string;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  newMessage() {
    this.data.changeMessage("Hello from Sibling")
  }
```

Personally, I would probably not use BehaviorSubject for parent-child or child-parent communication.

Rather, I would use it in two components that don't share anything and need to pass data between them. But in your case, it seems like a good solution.